# Cordova app Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I try to integrate Facebook login process into Cordova based app. I create Facebook app in developers center. The problem is that, I setup that app to work with my website

website: example.com

FB app domain: example.com
FB Site URl: http://example.com

So, what the problem. Cordova app has domain `localhost` and I can't add it to FB App domain.

I use this FB wrapper: https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB
setuped with this tutorial: http://hollyschinsky.github.io/ConferenceTracker/ionic-facebook-integration.html